# Is it ok to use a dictionary on the database for an app with lots of records?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I'm am working on an app which will handle lots of information and am looking for the best way of creating my models. Since I have never worked with apps that deal with so many records, database optimization is not a topic I know lots of, but it seems to me that a good design is a good place to start.

Right now, I have a table for customers, a table for products and a table for product-customer (since we assign a code for each product a customer buys). Since I want to track the balances, there is also a balance table. My models look like this at the moment:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    customer_ID= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, blank=True)
    product_active = models.BooleanField()

class ProductCustomer(models.Model):
    prod = models.ForeignKey(Product, db_index=True)
    cust = models.ForeignKey(Customer, db_index=True)
    product_customer_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    [...]

class Balance(models.Model):
    product_customer = models.ForeignKey(ProductCustomer, db_index=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch)
    [...]
```

**The app will return the 'history' of the customer. If the pax was overdue at some point and then he paid and then was due for a refund, etc.**

**I was thinking if I should insert a CharField on the Pax table which would hold a dictionary with date:status (the status could be calculated and added to the dictionary when I upload the information) or if it is more efficient to do a query on the Balance table, or if there is a better solution to be implemented.**

Since there are thousands of products and even more customers, we are talking about around 400K records for the balances on a weekly basis... I am concerned about what can be done to ensure the app runs smoothly.

Comment: 400K is not really a lot.  What database engine are you using?  That matters more than any other factor.  What web server and cache are you using?  That also matters more than anything else.

Comment: I know 400k is not a lot, but I meant you add about 400k each week, so they add up quickly. Right now I'm going to do the testing with sqlite3, but I have yet to decide on what will I use to implement the production version, as this is going to be only accessible from the intranet of the office. Any recomendation?

Comment: My advice would be design it however it seems correct to you, and take a look at performance considerations as and when you get them. As S Lott says the database engine will matter a great deal (MySQL and PostgreSQL are the most widely used free solutions).

Depending on your expected usage consider archiving to keep your 'current' working data performance predictable (endlessly growing datasets are unpleasant to maintain).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you seem to be asking about whether the join conditions will impose an unreasonable burden on your lookup query.  To some extent this depends on your rdbms.  My recommendation is that you go with PostgreSQL over MySQL because MySQL's innodb tables are heavily optimized for primary key lookups and this means two btrees have to be traversed in order to find the records on a join.  PostgreSQL on the other hand allows for physical scans of tables meaning foreign key lookups are a bit faster usually.

In general yes, the dictionary approach is fine for an app with lots of records.  The questions typically come out of how you are querying and how many records you are pulling in a given query.  That is a much larger factor than how many records are stored, at least for a db like PostgreSQL.